# ENOTFOUND - soap into rest with loopback

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, wsdl, strongloop

Few days ago I was looking for a way to consume SOAP Webservices with nodesjs. So after some researches, I've found loopback-connector-soap, it looks very amazing tool with a lot of possibilities.

So I "get started" here https://strongloop.com/strongblog/soap-into-rest-apis-with-loopback-node-js/

everything seems to be ok except two things :

1/ I have a ENOTFOUND when I launch the weather-rest server with an http link to the wsdl.

So I copy/paste the wsdl in a file and called it with 'path'

2/ now it's working but when I try the link : 
"/api/WeatherServices/forecast?zip=94555"
I have this page : 
[testing soap connector rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04VvZ.png,)
it's the same ENOTFOUND I had in 1/

So what could be the problem ?
Thanks for your help (and sorry for my english...)

Comment: Hey @kratos93, instead of directly cloning the connector, do you want to fork it? Or take your cloned repository and push it to a new repo on your own GitHub account? 

After that, I can take a quick look and see what's going wrong.

Comment: hi richard, No I cloned the connector : https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-connector/tree/soap but I can't call the Weather web service of the example (I tried some others web service, it's the same result) maybe it's a dns error ? I'm in a production network

Comment: That example isn't exactly up-to-date so I'll try it out and see what happens and respond on there.

Comment: update: it's working fine for me, it must just be your network

Comment: hmm ok thanks for this information, but it's weird because when I try the ws with SoapUI, it's working well. I have this problem only with the soap connector...

Comment: and you haven't made any adjustments to the code from the example? That seems very weird. Which version of node are you on (not that it should make a difference)?

Comment: nop, I just cloned it, I have changed nothing... my current version of node is 6.2.1